# setting Identityserver 'state' parameter as a GUID to correlate calls?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, identityserver3

I wish to correlate all the calls throughout **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectEvents** (OnRedirectToIdentityProvider, OnAuthorizationCodeReceived etc).

I wish to set the '*state*' parameter in *OnRedirectToIdentityProvider* as a GUID to later corralate the calls in logs, for example

```
 OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
 {
    var myGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    context.ProtocolMessage.State = myGuid;
    _log.LogInformation("OnRedirectToIdentityProvider: {0}", myGuid);

  ...
 },
 OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
 {
     _log.LogInformation("OnAuthorizationCodeReceived: {0}", context.ProtocolMessage.State);

  ...
 },
...
```

In the docs it is said that identityserver will echo back the state value on the token response. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html

I also read that client is responsible for the validation of this property.

The question is:

- I couldn't find any specific resource about when I want to use '*state*' property, *whether the validation is handled automatically by the middleware or should I handle the validation myself in a callback function*?
- *Is there any security risks I should consider when using GUID in a 'state' parameter*?
- *Pros/cons I should consider*?

Regards,
A

Comment: That's handled by middleware , state is unique and non-guessable ,GUID is ok for state parameter .

Comment: Thanks, found from the source code the
Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect() method.
After debugging and using this method, I can see that setting the ProtocolMessage.State value actually changes only AuthenticationProperties.Items["OpenIdConnect.Userstate"] value. All the other properties stay intact.

Comment: I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:
* Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core - https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

This is a **valid** approach to use **GUID as ProtocolMessage.State** property value.

After setting ProtocolMessage.State in OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event

```
context.ProtocolMessage.State = myGuid;
```

Found out from source code that data is being deserialized with StateDataFormat.Unprotect() method. I used this to debug

```
context.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect("CfDJ8...yr7Rpx3DyQMwPw")
```

'*state*' value in query is actually a serialized AuthenticationProperties class.

The AuthenticationProperties class is generated by the middleware and ProtocolMessage.State value is actually stored as **AuthenticationProperties.Items["OpenIdConnect.Userstate"]** in the response. 
As mentioned in the comment, middleware handles the validation of state.